# What might cause environment variables to be missing in my Flask app when deployed on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: flask, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I deployed a flask app to google cloud run and want to put some API keys into the environment variables (mostly to keep them out of github since I set up continuous deployment from there). However, when I configure the environment variables for the api keys, and I try to access them using the method the documentation says: `os.environ.get("API_KEY")`, I'm getting back none.

I tried printing out os.environ and the logs for the service show that the environment variables I configured aren't there (though there's a couple that GCP configured by default). The only potential issue I can think of is that the build directory that I'm deploying the app from is actually a sub-directory (stored within a folder in the github called `/backend-cloud-run`) which is where I point the cloud run and cloud build services to when I deploy.

What may be the issue / cause of the missing environment variables?

Also, I know that google secret manager exists as a recommended option for API keys and other sensitive information - but I'd prefer to start with these environment variables issues first. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

How are you configuring the environment variables?
You can deploy [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/4d4db9a93ef342b6661b697890a398f9db4c9602/run/helloworld) sample app from google and configure the environment variable "NAME". It should work, you can then compare what you are doing differently